# Web Proxy: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: xml, web-services, proxy

I am trying to make an outgoing HTTP call to a third-party webservice from a local webservice that I developed. The problem is that normally I am connected to a VPN as this is a corporate environment and if I am connected to the VPN, I get the error. If I disconnect the VPN, the HTTP call passes through just fine.

I've added this to the web.config of my webservice:

```
<configuration>
 <system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
   <proxy bypassonlocal="false" usesystemdefault="true" />
  </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Still not working... What additional steps do I need?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by adding this to the web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="true" proxyaddress="http://<proxy>:<port>/" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

I found out my organization's proxy URI from Internet Options, Under the Connections tab, select the VPN connection.